# Angular routerLink async state data

Tags: angular

How can I pass async data into [state] in routerLink?

users in this example is loaded async.

EDIT:
This does not work if I load the view before I get the data.
see code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-df6q16?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/home" [state]="users">Home</a>
```

Comment: Can you not use the `async` pipe, while binding it to a observable property in component?

Comment: Yeah just like that. Since it's binded to state then it means it will receive the value whenever that async call is finished and claimantSSN is changed. It looks fine whats the issue.

Comment: see edited above and code sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to @input instead of [state] in router.

The key was to use the "activate" event on router-outlet.

app.component.html:

```
 (activate)="onChildLoaded($event)"
```

app.component.ts:

```
 onChildLoaded(component: any) {
    if (component instanceof HomeViewComponent) {
      component.users = this.users;
    }
  }
```

See solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-854jta?file=src/app/views/home/home.component.ts